# Flexbox causes an unintended linebreak in Opera and Safari

Tags: html, css, webkit, flexbox

I’ve got a flexbox problem that occurs in Safari and Opera (probably Chrome also, haven’t checked). In Firefox everything looks as it’s supposed to. Here is the link: http://corvinweber.de/download/v5/

When you scroll down to the bottom of the page you’ll find the reply form. I want the fieldsets “.message” and “.senderforms” to be displayed next to each other, just like Firefox does it. However in Safari and Opera “.message” expands in width and “.senderform” gets pushed to the next line. Strangely, if I set the width of “.message” to 50 px “.senderforms” still gets pushed to the next line. The developer tool indicates that there’s a margin added to the right, although “margin-right” is set to 0.

I have also tried to use the -webkit-prefixed version of flexbox, but it didn’t help.

It’s probably just a small adjustment in the css, to make it work, but I can’t figure it out. Can someone help, please?

Answer (score 0):

Obviously the fieldset nested in another fieldset was the problem. I turned the outer one into a form and it worked.